# Jmeter HTTP authorization manager / NTLM login

Tags: jmeter, vpn, ntlm

First of all, yes I searched the web, and yes, there are similar questions all over the site. The thing is none of those answer my question.

I'm trying to **test a website with NTLM Authentication using Jmeter** (2.8). The problem is, it's simply impossible to pass the login popup window. On direct connection (AKA, without Jmeter running), the credentials are accepted and everything run just fine.

But when I start Jmeter's proxy to record the transactions, the browser hit the server, the login window popups and I enter the credentials, and it popups again and again and again (I even added the address to the Intranet trusted sites, and the login loop run for almost 45 minutes until I got tired and killed the browser process).

To clarify, my job's setup is composed by: Jmeter 2.8, running on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 (although I tried on my own laptop running Debian Wheezy and on my desktop running Windows 7, same results). I hit the customer server through a VPN (Cisco AnyConnect plugin) with no proxy on my company's side (apart of Jmeter's proxy of course).

I tried to use HTTP Authentication Manager + HTTP Cookie Manager + HTTP Request Defaults. I gave a try to the three HTTP implementations options (HTTP 3.1, 4 and Java). Being my credentials user: domain\username and password, I used:

- Base URL = http://subdomain.The-URL-where-the-login-must-popup.com/
- Username = Being domain\username, I just put the "username" part. (I tried with 3 different users)
- password = password
- Domain = the domain extracted from username (also tried leave it blank, putting the domain within the username, like domain\username).
- Realm = [blank]

With all these settings, the login never pass through. It justs loops asking for credentials forever.

Any idea? Where could it be the problem?
I accept any kind of suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried using the last nightly. No changes.

Comment: Do you have log errors ? what happens ? did you try to debug http traffic ? log_level.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

Try using JMeter nightly build:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

It relies on last version of HTTP Client 4.2.X which contains many fixes regarding NTLM.